# Lower bounding the sum of product of two sub-Gaussian variables where one follows an AR(1) process

Tags: autoregressive, bounds, tail-bound, subgaussianity

Suppose we have the sum

\begin{equation}
\sum_{t=2}^{n}\epsilon_{t-1}u_t
\end{equation}

where $\epsilon_t$ and $u_t$ are both sub-Gaussian variables. Further suppose that while $u_2,\cdots,u_n$ are i.i.d., $\epsilon_t$ follows an AR($1$) process, - i.e.,

\begin{equation}
\epsilon_t=\rho\epsilon_{t-1}+u_t,\quad \lvert\rho\rvert<1
\end{equation}

Suppose we are interested in lower bounding this sum. We know that product of two sub-Gaussian variables is sub-exponential. However, as $\epsilon_{t-1}$ for $t=2,\cdots,n$ are not independent, I thought the correct way would be to show the MA representation of $\epsilon_{t-1}$, as

\begin{equation}
\sum_{t=2}^{n}\sum_{i=0}^{t-1}\rho^iu_{t-1-i}u_t
\end{equation}
which is essentially
\begin{equation}
\sum_{t=2}^{n}u_{t-1}u_t+\rho\sum_{t=3}^{n}u_{t-2}u_t+\cdots+\rho^{n}u_{0}u_{n}
\end{equation}
where each sum (which are sum of sub-exponential variables) can then be individually lower bounded. I suspect, however, that I am over-complicating a very simple problem due to a gap in my knowledge. In which case, I would appreciate some help here.